# Объединение запроса к двум таблицам в базе данных через INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, mysqli, join, inner-join

Доброго времени! Такой вопрос: есть две таблицы ittems (предметы) и groups (группы)

ittems содержит поля id(INT 9 auto increment),name(VARCHAR 255)
groups содержит поля id(INT 9 auto increment),name(VARCHAR 255),idi(INT 9),stt(INT 9)

задача сделать выборку из таблицы ittems и к этой же выборке через JOIN закрепить выборку строк из groups если в groups есть строки у которых idi совпадает с id из ittems и stt равен 1
Делаю так:

```
  $$tmp = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ittems INNER JOIN groups ON ittems.id = groups.idt AND groups.nab='2' ORDER BY ittems.id ASC");
```

И при выводи информации:

```
$get = $tmp->fetch_array();
```

при попытке получить значение поля id из таблицы ittems

```
<?=$get['id'];?>  - выдает id таблицы groups как конкретизировать ключ?
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть ошибки распечатывали, mysql наверняка ругается на order by, потому что предложение order by может быть только в самом конце запроса. А вообще любые запросы лучше проверять не через php, а явно давая их mysql или давая ему же через более удобный инструмент вроде mysql workbench. Тогда не будете гадать почему 0 строк, потому что их 0 или по тому что ошибка, которую по ошибке могли не распечатать на экране

Comment: @Mike спасибо вот так сделал $tmp = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ittems INNER JOIN groups ON ittems.id = groups.idi AND groups.nab='2' ORDER BY ittems.id ASC"); - заработало как надо если конвертируете свой комментарий в ответ я смогу пометить вопрос закрытым)

Comment: Вряд ли ответ на него поможет кому либо еще. Нажал закрыть по "вызвано опечаткой"

Comment: @Mike а там нет такого пункта\

Comment: @Mike но я тут решил кое что другое спроситЬ!)

Comment: Такое наделю назад спрашивали, искать лень. Не выбирайте `*` _всегда_ явно перечисляйте поля, которые нужны. И если есть одноименные поля, переименуйте их алиасами `select ..., ittems.id as ittems_id ...` ну и в приложении оно будет в `$get['ittems_id']`. Кстати, а почему две буквы `t` в названии таблицы ;)

Comment: @Mike спасибо! две tt - не люблю слишком очевидные названия)